# How to convert file.ui into file.py with pyuic version 4.8.5?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, pyqt4, qt-designer, pyuic

I've had a problem converting *file.ui* into *file.py*, because I am using the 4.8.5 version of pyuic on my PC, and the version downloadable is 4.11 (for Python 3). I need to work with python 2.7 - how can I do it?

Comment: What file are you trying to convert? Where did you get it from?

Comment: firstly Install python 2.7 on your computer

Comment: Thank you ekhumoro. I am trying to convert file ui. I created the file with QT Desiner, version 4.8.5. My intention was to create a ui for QGIS that use Python 2.7 (for the moment).

Answer (score 1):

the command to convert the .ui file to .py is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-qt4
$  sudo apt install python3-pyqt4
$ sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools

pyuic4 -x mainw.ui -o filename.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem! I used the Windows shell, but I had to use that to Osgeo4W.

Comment: This unfortunately in not a helpful answer for anyone else who may have your problem in the future.  Could you describe the steps you used to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Heryx said, for me it was also necessary to use the OSGeo4W Shell (which is installed with QGIS2) to run pyuic4. In the OSGeo4W Shell i CD into the folder where my .ui file was and then successfully used the following command:

pyuic4 -x fileA.ui -o fileA.py